# StrongLoop remote methods route

Tags: routes, strongloop

By default in StrongLoop remote method is exposed as

http://apiRoot/modelName/methodName

This can be change for example to

apiRoot/modelName/differentMethodName

But I would like to know if there is possible to omit modelName in the route and make it only like:

http://apiRoot/differentMethodName

Thank you for answer,
Gregor

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

You can set `http.path` in `model.json` to customize `modelName` part in url.

```
//model.json

...
"http": {
  "path": "custom"
}
...
```